# $X$ is an infinite set. Prove that $S_X$ does not have proper subgroup of finite index.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Help

Denote by $S_X$ the group of permutations of $X$, i.e. the group of bijections $f:X\to X$ with composition.

Do we want to show $[S_X : H] = S_X?$

Comment: What is $H$? $\dots$

Comment: Maybe $H$ is an assumed proper subgroup of $S_X$ and $[S_X,H]$ is its index. (of course that index, if it exists, is not the same kind of object as $S_X$ itself, so the "want to show" line isn't technically right.)

Comment: The question doesn't make sense to me, somehow it's upvoted.

Comment: @Zero Either $S_X$ has a subgroup of finite index, or it doesn't. So IMO the question makes sense...

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to prove there is no normal subgroup of finite index, and it follows from the Schreier-Ulam-Baer theorem that the unique maximal normal subgroup of $S_X$ is the subgroup $S_{|X|}(X)$ of permutations which move strictly fewer than $|X|$ elements. To see that $[S_X:S_{|X|}(X)]=\infty$ you could for instance check that there is an element in $S_X$ all of whose powers move $|X|$ elements.

I wouldn't be surprised to see a simpler proof though, basically using something that looks like a small fraction of the proof of Schreier-Ulam-Baer.

Comment: No there are other approaches. Here we just need the easier fact that $S_X$ is generated by its elements of order $p$ for any prime $p$ (for an arbitrary group this rules out proper subgroups of finite index). This is maybe a little easier than the theorem you quote (conversely the Schreier Ulam Baer theorem certainly implies it).